# SAS_Stan.Dev for each minute

Tags: sas, standard-deviation

I want to ask a quick question. I think I can explain better by using simple sample.
So, I have the following data:

```
 Time          Value
 13:45          0.2
 13:45          0.4
 13:45          0.3
 13:46          0.1
 13:46          0.2
 13:46          0.3
 13:46          0.5
 13:46          0.4
```

I want to add one more column. The value in this column should be the standard deviation for each minute. So, I want to get the following data:

```
  Time          Value        St.D
  13:45          0.2           0.1  (it is the standard deviation of 0.2,0.4 and 0.3 - so st.dev for 13:45)
  13:45          0.4           0.1
  13:45          0.3           0.1
  13:46          0.1           0.1528  (it is the standard deviation of 0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5 and 0.6 - so st.dev for 13:46)
  13:46          0.2           0.1528 
  13:46          0.3           0.1528 
  13:46          0.5           0.1528 
  13:46          0.6           0.1528
```

Many thanks in advance for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare data:

```
data a;
  time ="13:45";
  value=0.2;
  output;
  time ="13:45";
  value=0.4;
  output;
  time ="13:45";
  value=0.3;
  output;
  time ="13:46";
  value=0.1;
  output;
  time ="13:46";
  value=0.2;
  output;
  time ="13:46";
  value=0.3;
  output;
  time ="13:46";
  value=0.5;
  output;
  time ="13:46";
  value=0.6;
  output;
run;
```

Calculate stddev:

```
proc summary data=a stddev nonobs noprint nway;
  by time;
  var value;
  output out=b(drop=_type_ _freq_) stddev()=;
run;
proc sql noprint;
  CREATE TABLE res AS
  SELECT a.*
      ,b.value as stddev
  FROM a
  LEFT JOIN b
  ON a.time=b.time
  ;
quit;
```

[image]

However the stddev of 13:46 differs from your expected. Moreover you have a little typo in you example data for 13:46 ([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6]).